# ui.bootstrap.tpls override template/datepicker/popup.html template

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, ui.bootstrap

I've created a new template/datepicker/popup.html template that get's loaded after ui.bootstrap.tpls.

What I'm struggling with is calling a function from ng-click in the new template. I **don't** want to update the ui.bootstrap.tpls file. I've attempted this two different ways:

1) **Less Ideal:** Use the select function already within directive datepickerPopup from ui.bootstrap.tpls. I can get this to work partially by converting to .toLocaleDateString() but after the first click I open the calendar again and the calendar still shows current date instead of reflecting the updated date.

```
"<button class='btn btn-default' ng-click='select(date.setTime(date.getTime()+30 * 86400000).toLocaleDateString())'>30 days</button>" +
```

2) **Ideal:** Create a brand new function outside of ui.bootstrap.tpls called addDays(n). I can't reach this function from the new template. I would like to create my own function to call from the new template.

```
"<button class='btn btn-default' ng-click='addDays(date, 30)'>30 days</button>" +
```

Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Klbek5SpOGIA4FXTmlFX?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent more time tinkering with this today and came up with a solution to my own questions.

When you override the template add ng-controller="ControllerName" to the outer element in my case a div. Then you need to add your controller to the module, in my solution I just added the controller right into the popupTemplate.js.

Updated Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YLJW2imcDAbzwsvp58Rl

Javascript FileName popupTemplate.js. Code:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module("template/datepicker/popup.html", [])

.run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
$templateCache.put("template/datepicker/popup.html",
    "<div ng-controller='ExampleCtrl'>" +
        "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\"  ng-style=\"{display: (isOpen && 'block') || 'none', top: position.top+'px', left: position.left+'px'}\" ng-keydown=\"keydown($event)\">\n" +
        "   <li ng-transclude></li>\n" +
        "   <li ng-if=\"showButtonBar\" style=\"padding:10px 9px 2px\">\n" +
        "       <span class=\"btn-group pull-left\">\n" +
        "           <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-info\" ng-click=\"select('today')\">{{ getText('current') }}</button>\n" +
        "           <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-danger\" ng-click=\"select(null)\">{{ getText('clear') }}</button>\n" +
        "       </span>\n" +
        "       <button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right\" ng-click=\"close()\">{{ getText('close') }}</button>\n" +
        "   </li>\n" +
        "</ul>\n" +
        "<div class=\"dropdown-menu-extend\" ng-style=\"{display: (isOpen && 'block') || 'none', top: position.top+'px'}\">" +
        "<h4 >or select a future date here...</h4>" +
            "<div class='col-lg-6'>" +
                "<h5>Add a new function</h5>" +
                "<button class='btn btn-default' ng-click='select(addDays(date, 30))'>30 days</button>" +
            "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "");
}])
.controller('ExampleCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.addDays = addDays;

  function addDays(date, days) {
    var newDate = date.setTime(date.getTime()+days * 86400000); //epoch date
    var finalDate = new Date(newDate); //formatdate
    console.log(finalDate);
    return finalDate;
  }
});

})();
```